# Showing dimensions on polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling, dimensions

I have a shapefile that contains all of the property parcel lines in King County, WA. We are currently displaying this data through mapbox on our site with no issues. We would like to be able to show (estimated) parcel dimensions (feet).

Is there anyway to extrapolate that information in qGis?

My thinking was to possibly add it to the attributes table so it could then be displayed as a label?

We'd need it to display something like this:

----------60 ft----------

Comment: You will need to break the polygons down into lines (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/how-can-i-transform-a-polygon-to-a-linestring-in-qgis) then calculate the geometry http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/calculating_line_lengths.html then display as normal labels. Trick is when to show and when not to show.

Comment: By parcel dimensions you mean polygon size in longitude and latitude axis? To be honest as far as I know for parcel sizes is used area...