# Extraction of line segments in front of the street

Tags: qgis, line, qgis-processing, extract

I have a layer of lines that represents a layer of plots. I want to eliminate all the inner segments to have only the segments that go out into the street. Thus, I want to determine the sum of the segments that lead to the road.
I started like this:
[image]

1. We removed the double segments with the function "Delete duplicate geometries"
2. I used dissolve on the group field to form a single line for a single plot.
3. I turned the lines into polygons.
4. I dissolved again on the resulting polygons to remain only with the contour of the plots, without the inner lines.
   [image]
5. I used "Extract by location", using the touch parameter to extract the face to the street (only the lines facing the street)
   [image]

This is the end result. Do you have any idea why these lines are broken and do not return the outline of my plot? Do you have any idea if there is a difference between layers? Or if not, you know some other way to extract these lines, but extract it from the original file, to keep the tabular data and segment characteristics.

[image]

After buffering the layer, it looks like this:
I set the tolerance of 0.00000001. However, I think it works even smaller.

[image]

Comment: Which line layer did you run the `extract by location` on?

Comment: On the initial layer of lines. "parcel lines" I did the other functions to get to a layer to use in Extract by location. There I need a layer for the parameter: By comparing to the future from, where I used the layer with dissolve.

Comment: Btw, you may be able to skip all the intermediate steps (1. - 4.) using DBScan https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#dbscan-clustering with epsilon 0 and minpoints 1 as with a eps distance of 0, the function effectively clusters by intersection only.

Comment: I used the function you told me. I set the parameters the way you said "minPTS = 1" and eps "0". Then I used extraction by location again, but it returns the same result as before. @Timothy Dalton

Comment: @TonyPasca if I understand correctly, would transforming your dissolved polygons to linestrings be enough? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/transforming-polygon-to-linestring-in-qgis

Comment: @Timothy Dalton , Yes, this would practically solve the problem, but the initial line file is processed in a model that joined the line segments at a certain angle. So I need these lines exactly as they are in the original file. (I only need those lines that are in front of the street)

Comment: I see, could you buffer the dissolved polygons by just a little bit and try the touch again? My guess why this is not behaving as you are expecting is the coordinates precision which don't match in all cases.

Comment: This method doesn't work either. He doesn't return anything to me.

Comment: Can you paste an image of the buffered dissolved polygons and the streets on top?

Comment: @Timothy Dalton , I edited the initial question. Take a look.

Comment: Can you try intersects now instead of touches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of step 5, create a new `geometry by expression` (go to `Menu Processing / Toolbox`), using the expression `boundary ($geometry)`, see:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is annoying when it is necessary to do an extraction of line segments and layer is **LinesSring** type (not **Polygon** type). It is because it depends of the way as lines were digitized. Your approach was correct but your "Extract by location" method doesn't have a "convexHull" option. In a PyQGIS script you can do that.

First, I downloaded your image and, it was arbitrarily projected with EPSG:32612 by me. Afterward, I digitized two blocks (LineString type); as it can be watched in following image. Observe that I also used the group field (in this case named block) to form a single line for a single plot with dissolve in my Python script.

[image]

Complete developed code looks as follows:

```
import processing

layer = iface.activeLayer()

parameters1 = { 'FIELD' : ['block'], 
                'INPUT' : layer, 
                'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

result1 = processing.run('qgis:dissolve', 
                         parameters1)

parameters2 = { 'INPUT' : result1['OUTPUT'], 
                'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

result2 = processing.run('qgis:fixgeometries', 
                          parameters2)

parameters3 = { 'INPUT' : result2['OUTPUT'], 
               'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

result3 = processing.run('qgis:linestopolygons', 
                         parameters3)

geoms_hull = [ feat.geometry().convexHull().asWkt() for feat in result3['OUTPUT'].getFeatures() ]
perimeters = [ feat.geometry().length() for feat in result3['OUTPUT'].getFeatures() ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer&field=length:double""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'Polygon',
                           'memory')
                           
prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(geoms_hull)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i, perimeters[i]])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(geoms_hull[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

When above code was run in Python Console of QGIS, I got result of following image. Convex Hull geometries (polygon features) perfectly match with each grouped features plot. In the attributes table it were also included your desired sums of the segments that lead to the road.

[image]